# With solidity and Web3, when I attempt to do myEvent.get() all I get is myEvent: undefined

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

Here is the part of my JS script where I get the event:

```
EthProj.Message({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }).get((error, eventResult) => {
        if (error)
            console.log('Error in setEvent event handler: ' + error);
        else
            console.log('setEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(eventResult.args));
    });
}
```

And here is my contract script:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract EthProj {
    
    string fName;
    string age;
    
    event Message(string name, string age);
   
    function setMessage(string _fName, string _age) public {
        fName = _fName;
        age = _age;
        
        emit Message(_fName, _age);
    }
   
    function getName() public constant returns (string) {
        return (fName);
    }
   
    function getMessage() public constant returns (string) {
        return (age);
    }
}
```

When I call setMessage I get undefined. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help? Am I not getting the events properly, or am I just not setting them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start a `watch` on the event before anything is returned. While a `watch` is running, you can receive new events as they come in or you can re-retrieve events again using `get`.

```
var events = EthProj.Message({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' });
events.watch((error, results) => {
  console.log(results); // Will show a single event object
});
events.get((error, eventResult) => {
  if (error)
    console.log('Error in setEvent event handler: ' + error);
  else
    console.log('Event count: ' + eventResult.length); // Notice object returned is an array
    eventResult.forEach(element => console.log('setEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(element)));
});
```